# How to specialize a templated class's member struct

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Say I have the following templated class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    struct store_t {
        uint8_t data[];
    } store;
    /// other stuff using T
}
```

Is there a way to construct a specialized version of the internal struct that would equate to something like this:

```cpp
class Foo {
    struct store_t {
        uint16_t f1;
        uint16_t f2;
    } store;
    /// other stuff using T
}
```

I would prefer to keep most of the "other stuff using T" unspecialized. I would specialize some accessors though.
I feel I would want to write something like

```cpp
template<>
struct store_t {
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
} Foo<someT>::store;
```

but that of course doesn't work.

Comment: Use another template parameter for the internal struct type i.e. `template <typename T, typename TInternal> class Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, I show another possible solution based over a sort of self-inheritance.

Suppose you want specialize `Foo` for the type `bool`.

You can write the main `Foo` adding a template non-type parameter with a default value (say a `bool` with a default value of `true`)

```
template <typename T, bool = true>
struct Foo
 {
    struct store_t
     { std::uint8_t data[10]; }   store;

    /// other stuff using T
    T value;
 };
```

I've added `T value` as example of "other stuff using T".

Now you can specialize `Foo<bool>` inheriting from `Foo<bool, false>`

```
template <>
struct Foo<bool> : public Foo<bool, false>
 {
    struct store_t
     { std::uint16_t f1, f2; }   store;
 };
```

This way you can specialize `store_t`/`store` (and other members, if you want) inheriting from `Foo<bool, false>` the "other stuff using T" (a `bool value`, by example).

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, bool = true>
struct Foo
 {
    struct store_t
     { std::uint8_t data[10]; }   store;

    T value;
 };

template <>
struct Foo<bool> : public Foo<bool, false>
 {
    struct store_t
     { std::uint16_t f1, f2; }   store;

    // inherits a bool value from Foo<bool, false>
 };

int main()
 {
   Foo<int>   fi;
   Foo<bool>  fb;

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(fi.value),
                               int>::value, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(fi.store.data),
                               std::uint8_t[10]>::value, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(fb.value),
                               bool>::value, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(fb.store.f2),
                               std::uint16_t>::value, "!");
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

As with most things in life, the answer to "how do I solve this problem I'm having with templates" is "use more templates."

#### Solution 1 - write `store_t` as a template

Thankfully, we don't have to do anything crazy. Let's write `store_t` outside of `Foo` as a template:

```
template<bool use_uint8>
struct Foo_store_t {
    uint8_t data[]; 
};
template<>
struct Foo_store_t<false> {
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
};
```

Now, when writing `Foo`, we can just pick which one we wanna use by testing some condition:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
    constexpr static bool use_uint8 = /* stuff */; 
    using store_t = Foo_store_t<use_uint8>; 
    store_t store;
};
```

#### Solution 2 - write two versions of `store_t`, use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

This one is also pretty straight-forward. `std::conditional` lets you pick between two different (arbitrary) types using a boolean.

```
struct store_A {
    uint8_t data[];
};
struct store_B {
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
};
class Foo {
    constexpr static bool useVersionA = /* stuff */; 
    using store_t = std::conditional_t<useVersionA, store_A, store_B>; 
};
```

Here I'm using `std::conditional_t`, which appears in C++14, but if you're restricted to using C++11 just do:

```
class Foo {
    constexpr static bool useVersionA = /* stuff */; 
    using store_t = typename std::conditional<useVersionA, store_A, store_B>::type; 
};
```